# Is it possible to use the same laptop/Xcode/device to develop for two separate companies simultaneously?

Tags: ios

I was wondering what the situation is for iOS contractors regarding certificate management etc.
If you work for company A then move on and work for company B I assume you can add get your device id first registered for development etc. with company A, install the certificates on your laptop/Xcode then delete everything when moving on to work for company B.
Any problems with that?

But is it possible to use the same laptop and device to do development and release work for both company A and company B simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose in Xcode the provisioning profile to be used for each project in the **Code Signing** section in the **Build Settings** tab. So if you work for many companies, you just have to make sure you select the correct ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can have provisioning profiles made for each app identifier that you are developing for, you just need to use your own private key. You can issue a provisioning profile for your client's app identifier under your own Apple account, and then send the app to your client for them to submit under their Apple account. There is no need for you to be a member of their Apple account's team, as all that gives your is access to their provisioning profiles (and you don't need that). I believe's Apple's goal here is to simply identify who specifically is signing code.

Do not create new private keys for each company, or even development certificates. Just reuse the one you have. Manage your various clients by creating new application IDs and provisioning profiles for each.